# combine nested xml nodes with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I am trying to combing the following two files:

## ls -lR test

```
test:
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx002 users 212 2013-11-25 17:36 file1.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx002 users 212 2013-11-25 17:36 file2.xml
```

## cat test/file1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Config>
   <HostGroup Name="X">
      <Host Name="A"/>
   </HostGroup>
   <HostGroup Name="Y">
      <Host Name="A"/>
      <Host Name="B"/>
   </HostGroup>
</Config>
```

## cat test/file2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Config>
   <HostGroup Name="X">
      <Host Name="B"/>
   </HostGroup>
   <HostGroup Name="Z">
      <Host Name="A"/>
      <Host Name="B"/>
   </HostGroup>
</Config>
```

Into the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<HostGroup Name="X">
   <Host Name="A"/>
   <Host Name="B"/>
</HostGroup>
<HostGroup Name="Y">
   <Host Name="A"/>
   <Host Name="B"/>
</HostGroup>
<HostGroup Name="Z">
   <Host Name="A"/>
   <Host Name="B"/>
</HostGroup>
```

So far, I have the following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

<xsl:variable name="collection">
        <xsl:copy-of select="collection('file:/home/xxx002/xslt/test/?select=*.xml;strip-space=yes;recurse=yes')/*"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="HostGps" select="$collection/Config/HostGroup"/>

<xsl:template name="foo" match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$HostGps" group-by="@Name">
                <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                <xsl:if test="not(./@Name = preceding-sibling::Property/@Name)">
                        <HostGroup>
                        <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:variable name="Hosts">
                                <xsl:perform-sort select="./Host">
                                        <xsl:sort select="@Name"/>
                                </xsl:perform-sort>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$Hosts"/>
                        </HostGroup>
                </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is not quite right.  It only picks up Host A in the first instance of HostGroup X.  Can anyone help me get past this?

Thanks,
Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to change the `select` attribute on the `xsl:perform-sort`.

This XSLT 2.0...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

    <xsl:variable name="collection">
        <xsl:copy-of select="collection('file:///C:/Users/dhaley/Desktop/so_test/?select=*.xml;strip-space=yes;recurse=yes')/*"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="HostGps" select="$collection/Config/HostGroup"/>

    <xsl:template name="foo" match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$HostGps" group-by="@Name">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(./@Name = preceding-sibling::Property/@Name)">
                <HostGroup Name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                    <xsl:variable name="Hosts">
                        <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()/*">
                            <xsl:sort select="@Name"/>
                        </xsl:perform-sort>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$Hosts"/>
                </HostGroup>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces...

```
<HostGroup Name="X">
   <Host Name="A"/>
   <Host Name="B"/>
</HostGroup>
<HostGroup Name="Y">
   <Host Name="A"/>
   <Host Name="B"/>
</HostGroup>
<HostGroup Name="Z">
   <Host Name="A"/>
   <Host Name="B"/>
</HostGroup>
```

Note: I also replaced your `xsl:attribute` with an [AVT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates) and added the `exclude-result-prefixes`. These aren't absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm just getting into transforms like this and I was so close... but could have spent days finding that!  Also, thanks for the additional cleanup work (getting rid of the xs, and optimizing the HostGroup Name element).

Comment: @user3034392 - You were very close. Nice work. I'm glad to see someone using XSLT 2.0. It seems like 99% of the XSLT questions are 1.0 only.